# How to run jobs in Next app locally with ESM that have path aliases?

Tags: node.js, typescript, next.js, es6-modules

EDIT: I changed my project to CommonJS from ESM and the alias works. I'd like to have it working in ESM, though.

I've tried pnpm and npm, `node` and `ts-node`, but I keep getting this error. `tsx` doesn't emit anything, so I assume it fails silently.

```
(master)> npx ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register -T src/server/jobs/index.ts
/node_modules/ts-node/dist-raw/node-internal-modules-esm-resolve.js:757
  throw new ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND(packageName, fileURLToPath(base));
        ^
CustomError: Cannot find package '@/server' imported from /src/server/jobs/index.ts
```

Here's the line it points to:

```
import sendSummariesJob from '@/server/api/jobs/send-summaries.ts'
```

Here's my `tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "checkJs": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "incremental": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Bundler",
    "noEmit": true,
    "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "rootDir": ".",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "ESNext",
    "types": ["node"],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["src/*"],
    },
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "next"
      }
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    ".eslintrc.cjs",
    "next-env.d.ts",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.js",
    "**/*.tsx",
    "**/*.cjs",
    "**/*.mjs",
    ".next/types/**/*.ts",
    "./src/*",
  ],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"],
  "ts-node": {
    "esm": true,
    "experimentalSpecifierResolution": "node",
    "require": ["tsconfig-paths/register"]
  }
}
```

The alias works when I run my Next app with `next dev`.
How can I use the `paths` aliases like I do in NextJS in the same project?

Comment: Replace `@/server` with `@/server/index.js` in your import statement. For esm, you need to have the file extension.

Comment: The import statement includes the extension: `import sendSummariesJob from '@/server/api/jobs/send-summaries.ts'`. Updated the question.

Comment: Change your `baseUrl` in `tsconfig.json` to `"./"`.